# Accessing request.user in a class based view

Tags: django

I want to display the current user when I load the template using this view. Is there a way to do it?

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'app/template.html'
    context_object_name = 'drinks'

def get_queryset(self):
    return Drinks.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a generic class based view or the render shortcut, then you can simply use `{{ user }}`, as long as `context_processors` includes `'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth'` in your `TEMPLATES` setting.

Answer (score 0):

In your `template.html`, you can use `{{ request.user }}` (for instance `{{ request.user.first_name }}`). If you require login, you can use `{{ request.user.is_authenticated }}`.